# Repeated messages to install ubuntu base on fully updated 20.04 desktop system. Why?

Tags: upgrade, updates

Just curious - is it normal after doing an apt-get update then upgrade to repeatedly receive messages telling me to install ubuntu base on my desktop computer?

Reading about what ubuntu base is makes me wonder why do I need it on an operating system?

[image]

I haven't clicked on "Install now" but usually do an apt-get update followed by upgrade.  And just doing only apt-get update, now I see:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Get:5 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease [4,501 B]                    
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Err:5 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                        
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:13 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease
Hit:14 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
E: The repository 'https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Insufficient data: Show us these messages.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for me to get around this was to completely remove Skype.  Now I have yet a different problem with skype repositories but since it doesn't specifically apply to this post, I'll just leave it solved.